Viewing the animation button isn’t working
When I press render than view animation it’s showing different animations that I made in the past even when I deleted them? Why is that.

Can you add some screenshots and perhaps share a small blend file demonstrating the problem https://blend-exchange.com

hello, maybe you have loaded the animation in the Video Sequencer? In that case delete it or Output panel > Post Processing > deactivate Sequencer

You have probably loaded an animation in the Video Sequencer, it will be rendered instead of your 3D scene, remove it or go into Output panel > Post Processing > deactivate Sequencer.
